# Take Photos Automatically - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to perform the task of taking a picture, but triggered by code instead of relying on the touching of the camera button in UIImagePickerController. Can this be done? I want to take a 10 pictures, 1 per second.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. And there is already an app for taking photos automatically, do a search in the app store with the keyword, **SneakyPix**

Comment: @diwup I am developing my own app for a completely different purpose than taking pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the AVFoundation framework -- that makes it pretty easy to do.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, Apple has documented [AV Foundation Media Capture](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2)

Answer (score 2):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348682/iphone-take-photo-with-front-camera-programmatically/9348734#comment11914049_9348734), check out Apple's [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) sample. It shows how to get both still images and video from the camera.