# iPhone : take photo with front camera programmatically

Tags: ios, camera

i want to take a picture programmatically by the front camera in my iphone app 
  i don't want the user to pick or do any interaction with the image picker .. just want to take the image and save it in the document.. is that possible?

Comment: possible dunplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237941/ios-take-picture?lq=1

Answer (score 8):

As I can understand from your question, AV Foundation is all you need.
Look at this demo sources from Apple: [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My bad, it seems you can actually do that from AVCaptureSession. Though I can't wrap my mind why should this be possible. Seems like a potential ground for abuse to me.

Original (wrong) answer:
No, it is not possible to take photos without user interaction, no matter if it's the front or back camera.

Comment: You'd think that, but nope. You can grab video frames without the user knowing at all, front or back camera. I think getting a high-res still image from the camera will always trigger the shutter sound.

Comment: Hmm, but from what framework? I thought all image capturing frameworks provide UI that user must activate to begin video/still image capture?

Comment: Check out AVCaptureSession. After setting up the input and output devices and starting the session, you get camera frames in the captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: callback. No UI needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this--

```
   - (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
          {
         // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
            ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
            reader.readerDelegate = self;
             reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

              ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
           // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

          // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
               [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];

          // present and release the controller
               [self presentModalViewController: reader
                         animated: YES];
               [reader release];
    }
    - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
        { 
          // ADD: get the decode results
             id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
               [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
               ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
               for(symbol in results)
                   // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
                      break;

                   // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
                      resultText.text = symbol.data;
                      bid.text=symbol.data;

                   // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
                      resultImage.image =
                      [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

                   // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
                      [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
                 }
```